# JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property Error with Jpa and Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

```
Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.bootapp.entity.Employee.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.bootapp.entity.Employee.user]]
```

User Entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
@JsonIgnore
@Getter @Setter
private Employee employee;
```

Employee Entity

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
@JsonIgnore
private User user;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
user.setEmployee(null); // I added this line
        userCommandService.save(user);
        employee.setUser(user);
        employeeCommandService.save(employee);
```

By setting employee inside the user entity to null, my error disappeared!

Comment: This didn't work for me. It's so frustrating, I have a NOT NULL column in the database, which should be able to tell Hibernate, that this is not necessary, it should just automatically allow one side to be inserted, Unnecessary over engineering